# How to add a gem using Bundler

Tags: bundler, gemfile

> ERROR: paperclip is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

to add `paperclip` gem in bundle list I tried the following:

```sh
bundle install paperclip
```

but yet again error occurs that is:

> Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./paperclip The path argument to bundle install is deprecated. It will be removed in version 1.1. Please use bundle install --path paperclip instead.

kindly assist me.

Answer (score 26):

Open `Gemfile` in your favorite text editor. Add the line `gem 'paperclip'`. Then run `bundle install`

Comment: john douthat i did what u said the follwing occurs:   Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./paperclip. But the paperclip gem is not bundled in it

Comment: i want paperclip gem to be placed in my Gemfie.lock

Comment: When you ran `bundle install paperclip` earlier, it thought you wanted to install your Gemfile gems into a folder called paperclip. It didn't think you wanted to install the paperclip gem. To fix the problem, delete the `.bundle/config` file, which is where bundler remembers what folder to install to, and delete the `paperclip` folder, just to clean things up. Then run `bundle install` (not `bundle install paperclip`) to get things back to normal. Hope that helps!

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, please post the contents of your Gemfile to the question.

Answer (score 20):

Another way to add a gem to the bundle is to run:

```
bundle add paperclip
```

The `bundle add` command seems to be supported since Bundler v1.15.

When you run `bundle add`, the requested gem is added to the Gemfile and the `bundle install` is being executed automatically so you don't have to run it yourself.

Comment: If you want Bundler to specify the exact version of the gem that was installed in your Gemfile then use `--strict` at the end of this command, like `bundle add paperclip --strict`. I highly recommend doing this to avoid any surprises in the future.